# Can't get mongoose to create new collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just getting to grips with MongoDB and Mongoose and struggling at the first hurdle!

I have a database called 'Academy' and have defined a schema called 'Level'. My understanding is that when I start up my Express server, the collection defined by the Schema model should be created automatically, but for some reason nothing seems to be happening. When I go to the database in the Mongo shell and type `show collections`, nothing is displayed.

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong? Do I need to input data as well as just define the Schema - I had hoped to create an empty collection for the time being and populate the data later.

Thanks!

Level schema definition:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LevelSchema = new Schema({
    level: Number, // e.g. 3
    framework: String, // e.g. England/Scotland
    sizes: [{
        name: String, // Award/Certificate/Diploma
        credits: Number // e.g. 11, 24, 48 etc.
    }],
    delivery: [], // Workshop/Distance
    venue: [], // Leeds/London/Edinburgh
    courseRef: String, // 600/7760/8
    units: [{
        number: String, // e.g. 01, 05 etc.
        name: String, // UnitName
        mandatory: [] // e.g. Award/Certificate/Diploma
    }]

});

const ModelClass = mongoose.model('Level', LevelSchema)

module.exports = ModelClass;
```

server.js - this uses http-proxy to set up a proxy server for development using Webpack - if you're interested, see [this article](http://www.christianalfoni.com/articles/2015_04_19_The-ultimate-webpack-setup) for more info. I don't think this is the reason I'm having trouble, however I left it all in there just in case.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


//DB SETUP

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function(){
    const Levels = require('./data/models/Level');
})
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Academy');


// SERVER SETUP
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

const app = express();

var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
var port = isProduction ? process.env.PORT : 3000;
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));


if(!isProduction){
    var bundle = require('./server/bundle.js');
    bundle();
    app.all('/build/*', function(req, res){
        proxy.web(req,res, {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080'
        });
    });
}

proxy.on('error', function(e){
    console.log('Could not connect to proxy, please try again...');
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you are doing something wrong. As soon as you will act against the Level model (find, insert etc) the collection should be created automatically.